# Getting two tangent circle tangent to their respective vector at a point?

Tags: geometry

Here's my problem

[image: Given A, B, v and u, find C1 and C2 ?]

I have two point $A$ and $B$, two vector $\overrightarrow{v}$ and $\overrightarrow{u}$.
I need to find the Center $C_1$ and $C_2$ of the circle $c_1$ and $c_2$.

$c_1$ is tangent to $\overrightarrow{v}$ at $B$.
$c_2$ is tangent to $\overrightarrow{u}$ at $A$.
$c_1$ and $c_2$ are tangent, this tangent point become $M$.
$c_1$ and $c_2$ have the same radius.

Some information we know :

$BC_1$, $C_1M$, $MC_2$, $C_2A$ are all segments of the same size.
$C_1M$, $MC_2$, are parallel.

There can be 4 solution at the same time, the ideal solution is when the shortest path to go to $M$ goes in the same direction as $\overrightarrow{v}$ from $B$ and $\overrightarrow{u}$ from $A$.

Comment: Welcome to this site! It's nice to see that you have described your problem in detail, the next thing you should do is to add to the question what you have tried and where/why you got stuck. That way you'll get help faster.

Comment: Do you want a numeric solution? If so, do you have any values at all of any of the  vars or points?

Comment: This problem is for a java program but I have a library with function based on geometric actions like "Line.intersectionOf(Line line)" or "Point.rotate(Point center, double angle)".
The points and vector are given at runtime and not predetermined.
So either way I can work this out with an algebraic or a geometric solution (I don't know if this is said that way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like a geometric solution. Here is the construction I did with The Geometer's Sketchpad.

No coordinate grid, points $A$ and $B$ are defined as you said, and the two vectors are represented as black lines. Let the two normals (red) meet at $C$, and suppose $AC < BC$.

[image]

Construct $D$ on $BC$, between $B$ and $C$, such that $BD = AC$. Let $E$ be the midpoint of $CD$. Let $F$ be the midpoint of $AB$. Consider any pair of points $P$ on $AC$ and $Q$ on $BC$, such that $AP = BQ$. In that case, the midpoint of $PQ$ must lie on line $EF$.

Now construct $G$ on $BC$, between $B$ and $C$, such that $CG = CA$. Construct the circle including points $A$, $G$, and $B$. Consider any pair of circles in this quadrant, tangent to the given lines at $A$ and $B$, and tangent to each other (example in blue). The point of tangency must lie on circle $AGB$.

Now two loci have been defined: line $EF$ and circle $AGB$, both shown in green. An intersection of these loci is a point of tangency for one pair of solutions. Intersections are shown for this case at $H$ and $J$. From there it is quick work to construct the circles.

For the other two pairs of solutions, let $D$ fall on the other side of $B$, and let $G$ fall on the other side of $C$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let the lines perpendicular to $u$ and $v$ at $A$ and $B$ respectively meet at $V$, and set: $VA=a$, $VB=b$, $\angle AVB=\alpha$ (if those lines are parallel then the solution is even simpler and is left to the reader).

Let then $x$ be the signed distance from $A$ to $C_2$ (positive if $A$ is between $V$ and $C_2$, negative otherwise) and construct $C_1$ on line $VB$ such that the signed distance from $B$ to $C_1$ is $\pm x$, using the same conventions for the sign. By the cosine law applied to triangle $VC_1C_2$ we have then:
$$
(a+x)^2+(b\pm x)^2-2(a+x)(b\pm x)\cos\alpha=4x^2.
$$
Solve these two equations to find the possible values of $x$.

[image]

EXAMPLE.

For the case illustrated in the question, we have:
$$
a=3,\quad b=4\sqrt2,\quad \alpha=45°.
$$

The quadratic equations above can then be solved for $x$. In the "$+$" case we get:
$$
x=\frac{1}{2} \left(-7+6 \sqrt{2}\pm\sqrt{189-118 \sqrt{2}}\right)\approx\cases{3.09438\\-1.6091},
$$
while in the "$-$" case we get:
$$
x=\frac{1}{2} \left(-7-6 \sqrt{2}
\pm\sqrt{189+118\sqrt{2}}\right)
\approx\cases{1.68971\\-17.175}.
$$
All those results correspond to valid solutions, as one can check with GeoGebra.

Comment: The answer has a great potential, with a bit of thinking I got to a similar equation without  using trigonometry

Comment: @y.petremann Of course, the same thing can be done in several different ways, for example using point coordinates. Note that the above equation works even if $a+x$ or $b\pm x$ are negative: in that case the change of sign is automatically taken into account by the switch from $\alpha$ to $\pi-\alpha$.